# Threading memory profiling

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-management, memory-leaks

So I hope this isn't a duplicate, however I either haven't been able to find the adequate solution or I just am not 100% on what I'm looking for. I've written a program to thread lots of requests. I create a thread to

1. Fetch responses from a number of api's such as this: share.yandex.ru/gpp.xml?url=MY_URL as well as scraping blogs
2. Parse the responses of all requests from the example above/ json/ using python-goose to extract articles
3. Return the parsed results back to the primary thread and insert into a database.

It's all been going well until it needs to pull back larger amounts of data which i haven't tested before. The primary reason for this is that it takes me over my shared memory limit on a shared Linux server (512mb) initiating a kill. This should be enough as it's only a few thousand requests, although i could be wrong. I'm clearing all large data variables/ objects within the main thread but that doesn't seem to help either.

I ran a memory_profile on the primary function which creates the threads with a thread class which looks like this:

```
class URLThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,request):
        super(URLThread, self).__init__()
        self.url = request['request']
        self.post_id = request['post_id']
        self.domain_id = request['domain_id']
        self.post_data = request['post_params']
        self.type = request['type']
        self.code = ""
        self.result = ""
        self.final_results = ""
        self.error = ""
        self.encoding = ""

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.request = get_page(self.url,self.type)
            self.code = self.request['code']
            self.result = self.request['result']
            self.final_results = response_handler(dict(result=self.result,type=self.type,orig_url=self.url ))
            self.encoding = chardet.detect(self.result)
            self.error = self.request['error']
        except Exception as e:
            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
            errors.append((exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno,e,'NOW()'))
            pass

@profile
def multi_get(uris,timeout=2.0):
    def alive_count(lst):
        alive = map(lambda x : 1 if x.isAlive() else 0, lst)
        return reduce(lambda a,b : a + b, alive)
    threads = [ URLThread(uri) for uri in uris ]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    while alive_count(threads) > 0 and timeout > 0.0:
        timeout = timeout - UPDATE_INTERVAL
        sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
    return [ {"request":x.url,
              "code":str(x.code),
              "result":x.result,
              "post_id":str(x.post_id),
              "domain_id":str(x.domain_id),
              "final_results":x.final_results,
              "error":str(x.error),
              "encoding":str(x.encoding),
              "type":x.type}
            for x in threads ]
```

And the results look like this on the first batch of requests i pump through it (FYI it's a link as the output text isn't readable in here, i can't paste a html table or embed an image until i get 2 more points ):

http://tinypic.com/r/28c147d/8

And it doesn't seem to drop any of the memory in subsequent passes (I'm batching 100 requests/ threads through at 1 time). By this i mean once a batch of threads is complete they seem to stay in memory ad every time it runs another, memory is added as below:

http://tinypic.com/r/nzkeoz/8

Am I doing something really stupid here?

Comment: Python doesn't always cleans up after itself, have a loo here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564782/ways-to-free-memory-back-to-os-from-python/24564983#24564983

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python will generally free the memory taken up by an object when there  are no references to that object left. Your `multi_get` function returns a list that contains references to every thread that you have created. So it's unlikely that Python would free that memory. But we would need to see what the code that is calling `multi_get` is doing in order to be sure.

To start freeing the memory you will need to stop returning references to the threads from this function. Or if you want to continue to do that, at least delete them somewhere `del x`.

Comment: Ah right okay that makes sense. The code that calls the multi_get function is just a simple loop through a list containing the requests with some additional data, it then loops through the results adn builds mysql inserts. So if I transform the thread objects into a list or some other simpler object/variables, delete threads and return the object (not the threads) from multi_get that might work right?

Comment: Yup, that will do it. Try just returning Python primitives (like strings) from your `multi_get` function. That might do the trick.