# Thread Pool giving OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python, out-of-memory, threadpool

The code runs smoothly for quite some time, then suddenly it gives ***OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory***

```
def initialize(site):
    global pool

    if site == 'OT':
        for jobId in JobIdsOT:
            argumentList = [jobId, site]
            pool.map(assignTask, [argumentList])            

    elif site == 'LI':                
        for jobId in JobIdsLI:
            argumentList = [jobId, site]
            pool.map(assignTask, [argumentList])
```

---

StackTrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LogDumper.py", line 301, in <module>
    main()
  File "LogDumper.py", line 58, in main
    initialize('OT')
  File "LogDumper.py", line 78, in initialize
    pool.map(assignTask, [argumentList])            
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 148, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 422, in get
    raise self._value
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

I referred this question [Python cannot allocate memory using multiprocessing.pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717120/python-cannot-allocate-memory-using-multiprocessing-pool) . But I am not sure about the solution.

How can I resolve the aforementioned issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change to.

```
for jobId in JobIdsOT:
        argumentList.append( (jobId, site) )
 pool.map(assignTask, argumentList)
```

`pool.map(...` expect only one `iterable` and has to be called only once for all job's.