# garbage collecting python rss memory

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, rss

I'm profiling my Python program, I'd like to know how much memory it's using and if there's any way I can clear it out, I notice that it's using a lot of rss memory, the way I do the profiling is this:

```
p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print p.get_memory_info()
```

I noticed that the rss memory used increases dramatically after I call a few functions, and I'd like to delete the variables after I'm done. How can I do so that rss memory clears out? But if I do:

```
p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print p.get_memory_info()
ll = []
ll.append(ll)
print p.get_memory_info()
```

There is no memory allocated in rss.

What exactly gets put in the rss? And any way I can clear it out? Is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 1):

According to [psutil docs](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.memory_info), `rss` refers to different value depending on your OS:

> Return a tuple representing RSS (Resident Set Size) and VMS (Virtual
>   Memory Size) in bytes. On UNIX rss and vms are the same values shown
>   by ps. On Windows rss and vms refer to “Mem Usage” and “VM Size”
>   columns of taskmgr.exe.

Assuming you are on Linux, RSS (from [What you can find out about the memory usage of your Linux programs](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/LinuxMemoryStats)):

> a process's RSS is just how many page table entries in its virtual
>   memory areas point to real RAM (...) Your process's RSS increases
>   every time it looks at a new piece of memory (and thereby establishes
>   a page table entry for it).

You can instrument Python interpreter to run [garbage collection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.collect).

Check [this SO post answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python) and this [FAQ entry](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm) for more details.