# Memory leaking in cpython 2.7

Tags: python, memory, cpython

For example i have a code that produces many integers.

```
import sys
import random
a = [random.randint(0, sys.maxint) for i in xrange(10000000)]
```

After running it i got VIRT 350M, RES 320M (view by htop).

Then i do:

```
del a
```

But memory still is VIRT 272M, RES 242M (before producing integers was VIRT 24M, RES 6M).

The pmap of a process say that there are to big pieces of [anon] memory.

**Python 3.4 does not have such behavior: memory are frees when i delete list here!**

What happens? Does python leave integers in memory?

Comment: Try forcing the garbage collector after you `del a`. `import gc; gc.collect()`.

Comment: >>> gc.collect()
0. Memory still not frees.

Comment: Take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I can duplicate it. If I start python 2.7, the interpreter uses about 4.5 MB of memory. (I'm quoting "Real Mem" values from the Mac OS X Activity Monitor.app).

```
>>> a = [random.randint(0, sys.maxint) for i in xrange(10000000)]
```

Now, memory usage is ~ 305.7 MB.

```
>>> del a
```

Removing `a` seems to have no effect on memory.

```
>>> import gc
>>> gc.collect()   # perform a full collection
```

Now, memory usage is 27.7 MB. Sometimes, the first call to `collect()` doesn't seem to do anything, but a second `collect()` call will clean things up.

But, this behavior is by design, **Python isn't leaking.** [This old FAQ](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm) on effbot.org explains a bit more about what's happening:

> “For speed”, Python maintains an internal free list for integer objects. Unfortunately, that free list is both immortal and unbounded in size. floats also use an immortal & unbounded free list.

Essentially, python is treating the integers as singletons, under the assumption that you might use them more than once.

Consider this:

```
# 4.5 MB    
>>> a = [object() for i in xrange(10000000)]
# 166.7 MB
>>> del a
# 9.1 MB
```

In this case, python it's pretty obvious that python is not keeping the `object`s around in memory, and removing `a` triggers a garbage collection which cleans everything up.

As I recall, python will actually keep low-valued integers in memory forever (0 - 1000 or so). This may explain why the `gc.collect()` call doesn't return as much memory as removing the list of `objects`.

---

I looked around through the [PEPs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/) a bit to figure out why Python3 is different. However, I didn't see anything obvious. If you *really* wanted to know, you could dig around in the source code.

Suffice to say in Python 3, it either the number-singleton behavior has changed, or the garbage collector got better.

Many things are better in Python 3.

Comment: I call gc.collect() many times, but memory is still occupied (Linux, Kubuntu 15.04, 3.19.0-25-generic, x86_64).

Comment: Hi @Pavel - I tried on an Mint 17.2 (Ubuntu 14.04 - 3.13.0-37) machine with python 2.7.6. The test array uses VIRT 348M RES 316M. `del a` reduces this to VIRT 270M RES 240M. So for me, some memory is freed, possibly just the list. I don't see any [obvious bugs](https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/v3.4.3/Misc/NEWS) that seem to be related to this, so it's _possible_ that this is a new bug. However, if this problem is more than a curiosity for you and is holding you up, I'd suggest using a generator instead of a list, or if you really need a list, do your work in a child process.

Comment: Seth, it is not a "critical bug" for my code, but it is very interesting.