# Is it good idea to change variable to 0 to save memory in python?

Tags: python, memory-management

I've searched and couldn't find any good answer. Let's say that I have some list that have thousands of entries or something else that consumes a lot of memory. Is it good idea to change this list/etc. value to 0...

```
oldlst = 0
```

...if it's no longer needed (or won't be updated in a very long time) or should I leave it alone in program. Or maybe there is better way to handle this.

Example:

```
L = range(50*2000*1000)
raw_input("Press Enter")
L = 0
print L
```

When I run this command I use 838.1 MB of RAM
after pressing enter and changing L to just 0 I release some of the memory taken

Comment: That will decrement the list's reference count, so it can be garbage collected if nothing else has a reference to it. However it's not clear why you think you need to do this; could you instead use e.g. scoping more sensibly so that its references are released when you've finished using it (e.g. at the end of a function)? Could you provide a more concrete [mcve] of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: use del oldlst` :-)

Answer (score -3):

You need to think on releasing memory rather than making list to 0 once not required.

Please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python)