# Celery not release memory after get result

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am a newbie in python, I'm starting and having trouble with celery and flask, are looking forward to getting the help of you. (Sorry if my English is not good)

I'm testing with a small project using celery and flask, my program will use flask to send requests to the celery worker retrieved content is then returned to the user, however, after testing I saw after the call the `function get()` of celery, it seems does not release the memory for the ram volume used convincedthat increased to very high After `memory_profiler`, I see the results as follows:

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
42   32.605 MiB    0.000 MiB   @app.route('/test2')
43                             @profile
44                             def test2():
45   32.605 MiB    0.000 MiB       url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
46   42.641 MiB   10.035 MiB       request_get.delay(url).get()
47   42.641 MiB    0.000 MiB       url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
48   45.422 MiB    2.781 MiB       request_get.delay(url).get()
49   45.422 MiB    0.000 MiB       url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
50   47.992 MiB    2.570 MiB       request_get.delay(url).get()
51   47.992 MiB    0.000 MiB       url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
52   55.102 MiB    7.109 MiB       request_get.delay(url).get()
53   55.102 MiB    0.000 MiB       url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
54   57.441 MiB    2.340 MiB       request_get.delay(url).get()
```

Didn't know there was anybody having the same problem and there is no workaround, thanks for reading

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python

Comment: Thanks @TomDalton , I have tried gc.collect() but not working, I recently started with python, can you help me more detail?