# Process takes a long time to terminate, stuck in a stream of munmap

Tags: python, python-2.7, mmap, dbm

I have a Python 2.7 process (started by `cron`) on a Linux box that takes a *very* long time (10s of *minutes*) to terminate.
While it is running, it uses a lot of memory (25GB) and it appears to take a lot of time releasing it.

`strace` reports an endless stream of

```
munmap(0x7fd5cd411000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb5d1000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb591000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb611000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb551000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5ccb11000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc991000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc951000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc591000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5ccb91000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5ccb51000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc291000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc251000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc211000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc1d1000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cda11000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cd111000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cd0d1000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc4d1000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc411000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc151000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cc091000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb911000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb8d1000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb891000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb451000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb391000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb3d1000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cb351000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x7fd5cd5d1000, 262144)          = 0
```

`ltrace` reports nothing.

While it was alive, it used a GDBM database, but have been closed long ago. The open file descriptors are:

```
0 lr-x------ 1 sds sds 64 May 24 20:05 0 -> pipe:[36989242]
0 l-wx------ 1 sds sds 64 May 24 20:05 1 -> pipe:[36989243]
0 l-wx------ 1 sds sds 64 May 24 20:05 2 -> pipe:[36989243]
0 l-wx------ 1 sds sds 64 May 24 20:05 3 -> /home/sds/my/path/file.log
0 lr-x------ 1 sds sds 64 May 24 20:05 9 -> /dev/urandom
```

It will not write anything to the log file.

What is going on here? Is that an artifact of [Python GC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455048/850781)? GDBM?

Is there anything I can do (besides `kill`)?

Comment: are you on python 2.7?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: yes

Comment: munmap by itself should be fast, since the VMAs in the kernel are managed in a red-black tree. An easy way to understand what the process is doing is to use the "poor man's profiler": Attach gdb while it is running, and use the `where` command to see the stack trace. Then `detach` it again. Do this 10 times.