# Is it possible for a Python function to still use memory after being called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

If I run a function in Python 3 (`func()`) is it possible that objects that are created inside `func()` but cannot be accessed after it has finished would cause it to increase its memory usage?

For instance, will running

```
def func():
    # Objects being created, that are not able to be used after function call has ended.

while True:
    func()
```

ever cause the program run out of memory, no matter what is in `func()`?

If the program is continually using memory, what are some possible things that could be going on in `func()` to cause it to continue using memory after it has been called?

Edit:
I'm only asking about creating objects that can no longer be accessed after the function has ended, so they should be deleted.

Comment: Short answer is yes - `non_local_list.append(1)` would be a trivial example.

Comment: Can you explain why you want such behavior? Maybe this site is out of scope...

Comment: Another trivial example: `def f():''; f.__doc__ += ' '`

Comment: @Y0da, I don't want this behaviour, but I have a function that seems to act like this, and I thought all objects in a function are deleted upon exit of the function.

Comment: In that case, you need to show us a [mcve] that exhibits this behaviour. We can't debug code that we can't run or even see.

Comment: Yes I appreciate that, and I am creating one, but I just wanted to check that it was possible there was a problem first (and I wasn't just going crazy!)

Comment: Python functions are [*not pure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), they are allowed to touch anything in the Python runtime they can lay their hands on. The Python runtime is inherently introspectable and mutable, so *in general* you can't trust functions to not eat memory. There are numerous ways of making objects grow from a function, too many to recount. Perhaps you want to focus on a specific case instead?

Comment: @Shiva I don't think this question is too broad because it is straight forward and can be sufficiently answered in a couple paragraphs. I think this question should be reopened.

Comment: @PM2Ring There may be a debugging issue that prompted this question but that's beside the point. I don't think a M.C.V.E. should be required because this question isn't about debugging.

Comment: @cpburnz As Martijn says, there are numerous ways of making objects grow from a function, so an answer consisting of a couple of paragraphs will be rather general. IMHO. But if the OP can narrow down the scope of the question with a MCVE containing specific code that may cause unexpected memory gobbling, then I'm happy to cast a re-open vote.

Comment: @PM2Ring I think you're focusing too much on the potential problem rather than the actual question itself. If the OP wants to know why a specific function doesn't seem to release memory, then he by all means should provide an M.C.V.E. But he's asking more of a general question to which a general answer similar to Martjin's comment would suffice.

Comment: @cpburnz the question that you're suggesting be answered is not the question that is asked here. That question would be: _"Can Python functions access variables that exist outside of the function definition?"_

Comment: I've added an addendum to the bottom that should help to make it less broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for a Python function to still use memory after being
called.

- Python uses garbage collection (GC) for memory management. Most GCs (I suppose
  there could be some exceptions) make no guarantee if or when they will free
  the memory of unreferenced objects. Say you have a function
  `consume_lots_of_memory()` and call it as:

  ```
  while True:
      consume_lots_of_memory()
  ```

  There is no guarantee that all of the memory allocated in the first call
  to `consume_lots_of_memory()` will be released before it is called a
  second time. Ideally the GC would run after the call finished, but it
  might run half way through the fifth call. So depending on when the GC
  runs, you could end up consuming more memory than you would expect and
  possibly even run out of memory.
- Your function could be modifying global state, and using large amounts of
  memory that never gets released. Say you have a module level cache, and a
  function `cache_lots_of_objects()` called as:

  ```
  module_cache = {}
  while True:
      cache_lots_of_objects()
  ```

  Every call to `cache_lots_of_objects()` only ever adds to the cache, and
  the cache just keeps consuming more memory. Even if the GC promptly
  releases the non-cached objects created in `cache_lots_of_objects()`, your
  cache could eventually consume all of your memory.
- You could be encountering an actual memory leak from Python itself (unlikely
  but possible), or from a third-party library improperly using the C API, using
  a leaky C library, or incorrectly interfacing with a C library.
- One final note about memory usage. Just because Python has freed allocated
  objects, it does not necessarily mean that the memory will be released from the process
  and returned to the operating system. The reason has to do with how memory is
  allocated to a process in chunks (pages). See abarnert's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508271/369450)
  to [Releasing memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455048/369450)
  for a better explanation than I can offer.

Comment: Thanks! This is really useful. Especially the first and last points. Am I right in saying that I can force the GC to collect using `gc.collect()`?

Comment: @Gloin Yes, that's correct. I've had to use that once myself when generating a large export.