# When is data freed?

Tags: python

Does Python do any analysis to free memory earlier? For example, if I have:

```
d = some big array
# ... use(d) ...

# no d is used from here
# a lot of other code, the code could use more big arrays
```

When does python decide to delete the memory used by `d`?

If I use `d` in a function, will `d` be freed when the function is done?

Maybe in general this is hard, because `d` can be assigned to others, and they may continue using `d` after the function is finished.

However, I was looking for some good practice that can keep python use less memory...

Comment: Use `del d` when you won't be using `d` anymore.

Comment: @nsilent22 It just dereference the name `d` but won't actually delete the array from memory (unless it was the only reference).

Comment: Like many languages, Python uses a garbage collector.  But the details of garbage collection are implementation defined.  Most implementations that I know of use reference counting, so like @nsilent22 mentioned, using `del` can remove references to objects, making them eligible to be GC'd.

Comment: Garbage collector handles it. See how it works https://www.quora.com/How-does-garbage-collection-in-Python-work

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your case `del d` to dereference the array when you are finished with it, but Python will take care of the memory itself after your program is finished running. I found 2 other questions that are similar and may delve deeper into memory management in python here are the links:

[How can I explicitly free memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python)

and its answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316793/6475414

and:

[Releasing memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit to the situation when d is used in function, it depends on when d is declared. If d is declared within the function, and there is no inner function referencing d, it will be garbage collected.

for example:

```
def outer():
     d = np.arange(10000)
     def inner():
         d += 1
         return d
     return inner
```

in this case d will still reside in the memory if after `outer()` function is returned.