# memory leak unpickle dict of pandas DataFrames

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, pickle

When I pickle a dictionary of dataframes and then unpickle them again, I experience a kind of memory leak. After the unpickled variable is dereferenced, the memory is only released partially. Calling `gc.collect()` does not help. I have created the following minimal exmaple:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
new =  np.zeros((1000, 100))
new = pd.DataFrame(new)
cc = {ix: new.copy() for ix in range(500)}
pickle.dump(cc, open('/tmp/test21', 'wb'))
```

Now I open a clean python session and do

```
import pickle
# memory consumption is around 40MB
data = pickle.load(open('/tmp/test21'))
# memory consumption goes to 991MB
data = None
# memory consumption goes to 776MB
```

This is pandas 0.19.2 and python 2.7.13. The problem seems to be the interaction between pickle, dictionary and pandas. If I remove the line `new = pd.DataFrame(new)`, the problem does not occur. If I simply make a large df without a dictionary, the problem does not occur. If I don't pickle the dictionary and set `cc = None`, the problem does not occur. I have also tested the problem with pandas 0.14.1 and python 2.7.13. Finally the problem appears with both pickle and cPickle.

What could be the reason or a strategy to analyze this further? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have relatively large RAM? Perhaps, memory is released back to the OS when the free amount reaches a critical amount i.e. runtime might be keeping "freelists" for future allocations. Can you try creating a large object and then `del` it to see how it affects things? For example, `b = np.random.rand(1000, 2000, 300)`.

Comment: Might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python

Comment: b = np.random.rand(1000, 2000, 300) pushes memory consumption to 4.5GB. b=None releases back to 53MB exactly where I started from.

Comment: Regarding stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-pyt‌​hon . It seems that `gc.collect()` is able to free up the memory almost entirely for the example presented. In my case dereferenncing brings it down to a bit more than half but gc.collect does not change consumption at all.