# Efficient way to clear memory while removing DF python 3 pandas

Tags: python, memory-management

**Hi!**

Is there any efficient way in python 3 to release memory after removing object?

```
del DF
DF = pd.DataFrame()
gc.collect()
```

None of those is working properly. Only working approach is to `DF.to_csv` after working on it, restart the script and `read_csv` - that is really annoying.

`from SecureString import clearmem` - works fine in python 2, however it is not supported in python 3

Do you know any similiar method to SecureString that works in python 3?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: It is garbage-collected python's decision to release memory. In general you cannot do that. `SecureString` is only meant to be used for cryptographic usecases. Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python