# Why are nested lists leaking memory on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks

I am getting "high water mark" memory leak behavior when I run:

```
import gc
temp = [[0.1] for _ in xrange(10 ** 7)]
del temp
gc.collect()
```

The resident memory starts at ~7 MB climbs to ~1000 MB and then settles at ~312MB. Subsequent runs do not increase the memory leak above 312 MB. Why does this happen and are there any known work arounds?

Various observations:

1. It happens on Ubuntu 14.04 but not on OSX
2. It does not happen in python3
3. `[[] for _ in xrange(10 ** 7)]` does *not* leak
4. `[0.1 for _ in xrange(10 ** 7)]` does *not* leak
5. `[(0.1,) for _ in xrange(10 ** 7)]` does *not* leak
6. `[0.1 for _ in xrange(10 ** 7)]` does *not* leak
7. `{random.random(): {0.1: 0.1} for _ in xrange(10 ** 7)}` *does* leak
8. Clearing the individual lists one at a time doesn't help
9. Running in the python shell vs in a file doesn't seem to have an impact
10. I have reproduced the behavior in python versions: 2.7.15, 2.7.14, 2.7.11, and 2.7.5

My first intuition was that it's caused by arenas not getting cleaned up.  But that didn't make sense because I would expect the same behavior with `[0.1 for _ in xrange(10 ** 7)]` but that doesn't happen.

Why does nesting the list/dictionary result in this high water mark behavior?

I am primarily measuring the resident memory using `htop`

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455048/5320906