# Python flask threads does not close

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, garbage-collection

My python `flask` app runs using `nohup`. ie it is always live. I see that it creates a thread every time user submits from page. It is because flask.run is with `multithread=true`. But my problem is even after the processing is over, the thread doesn't seem to be closed. I'm checking this with the `ps -eLf |grep userid` command. where i see many threads still active long after the code execution is over. and it gets added when another submit is done. All threads are removed when the app itself is restarted.

What is the criteria for the thread to close without restarting the app?

Many posts like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python/15457947#15457947) suggests the `gc.collect`, `del object` etc.. 
I have many user defined classes getting instantiated on submit. and one object refers another . So

is it because the memory not getting released?

Should i use `gc.collect` or `del objects`? 
Pythons should be clearing these objects once the `scope` of the variable is over. is it correct?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/submit',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def submit():
    #obj1=class1()
    #obj2=class2(obj1)
    #obj3=class3(obj1)
    #refer objects
    #process data
    #done

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000, threaded=True, debug=False)
```

Comment: Flask's built-in development server really isn't intended for multithreaded use, hence the lack of support for thread management. I'd suggest reading into the pros and cons of the recommended deployment servers and see which suits your needs best. Popular choices: Gunicorn, Twisted, SocketIO, Gevent, nginx.

Comment: this is also comparatively a small web app . but few users uses simultaneousely. so didnt look for a better platform than  flask. I would definitely look at one of these above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was with a `paramiko` object not getting closed. Once the `SFTPClient` or the `SSHClient` is opened, it has to be closed explicitly. I have assumed that along with my class object (where paramiko object is defined) it would get closed. But it doesnt.

So on the end of my process i call below lines. Now the threads seems getting closed properly

```
    if objs.ssh:
        objs.ssh.close()
    if objs.sftp:
            objs.t.close()
            objs.sftp.close()
    del objs
    gc.collect()
```