# Gunicorn worker doesn't deflate memory after request

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have a single gunicorn worker process running to read an enormous excel file which takes up to 5 minutes and uses 4GB of RAM. But after the request was finished processing I noticed at system monitor that it stills allocating 4GB of RAM forever. Any ideas on what to do to release the memory?

Comment: Short form: Don't worry about it. If it's not actively being used, it'll be swapped out; the virtual memory space remains allocated, but something else will be in physical memory. Many allocators *won't ever* release memory back to the OS -- it just releases it into a pool that application will malloc() from *without needing to ask the OS for more* in the future.

Comment: I'm split on whether to flag this as a duplicate of [Releasing memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python). Whether or not they're duplicates, it's certainly a very pertinent read.

Answer (score 7):

You may try setting the max-requests (N) parameter for a gunicorn worker to indicate to restart the worker after processing N number of requests.

You can refer for more on the max-requests settings here: 
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html

Comment: Thanks for this good hint. I think it is a good idea to force a restart of a worker from time to time. ;)

Comment: I just found out that this restart causes a second or so hiccup where gunicorn resets the connection of clients causing some error noise when traffic is high. So if you use it, make it a high number (10K+), add a large jitter (20%) and keep in mind that Benoit doesn't recommend it in production: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/3038#issuecomment-1887073067