# Left-overs after garbage collection

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I wonder if I create a large list, for example,

```
l = list(range(0, 10000000))
```

and then set it free for the garbage collector

```
l = None
```

it does not release all memory (according to `memory_profiler`):

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     8    427.3 MiB    382.7 MiB           1       l = list(range(0, 10000000))
     9    122.3 MiB   -305.0 MiB           1       l = None
```

What is about the remainder?

Comment: Python doesn't necessarily release the memory back to the OS, even if it knows it's no longer using it. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python.

Comment: How rude! :) Thanks for the comment. Maybe you would like to answer this to my question so that I can upvote your answer and mark it as answered.