# Python multiprocessing with an iterable of functions

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a list with a high number of different ML models `model_trace`. If I do something like:

```
import gc

for model in model_trace:
    model.predict(test_data)
    del model
    gc.collect()
```

The kernel gets killed at some point because the used RAM increases over time (it is no problem at all to use the predict function of the separate models). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455048/releasing-memory-in-python) I read that there is no way to force Python to release all memory, so I tried using child processes with `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial


def predict_(model, test_inputs_=None):
    return model.predict(test_inputs_)

worker = partial(
    predict_, 
    test_inputs_=x_test, 
)

pool = Pool(4)
preds = pool.map(worker, model_trace)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

But this produces a `Too many open files` error. For a small number of models, it works, while running a loop with small batches of models also produces the  `Too many open files` error.

The following works:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def predict_(test_inputs_):
    return model.predict(test_inputs_)
    
    
for model in model_trace:
    with Pool(1) as pool:
        res = pool.apply(predict_, (x_test,))
```

However, I can't put this code inside a function `run_predictions`, as this produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'run_predictions.<locals>.predict_'
```

Also as I use multiprocessing and the predictions could be done in parallel it woudnt feel natural to just run the predictions one after the other.

If I don't wrap `model.predict(geometries_test)` inside the `predict` function, I get get the `Too many open files` error again and I also observe how the number of open files increases with every iteration. `pool.terminate()` does not change this.

The models of the model trace I use are GaussianProcess models for which I use gpytorch. The following example model trace produces the described errors:

```
import copy
import torch
import gpytorch
import math


class GaussianProcessRegression(gpytorch.models.ExactGP):

    def __init__(self, likelihood):
        super(GaussianProcessRegression, self).__init__(None, None, likelihood)

        self.likelihood = likelihood
        self.mean_module = gpytorch.means.ZeroMean()
        self.covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.ScaleKernel(gpytorch.kernels.RBFKernel())

    def forward(self, inputs):
        mean = self.mean_module(inputs)
        covar = self.covar_module(inputs)
        return gpytorch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(mean, covar)

    def fit(self, train_inputs, train_targets):
        train_inputs = (train_inputs,)
        self.train_inputs = tuple(tri.unsqueeze(-1) if tri.ndimension() == 1 else tri for tri in train_inputs)
        self.train_targets = train_targets

        # train mode on
        self.train()
        self.likelihood.train()
        
    def predict(self, test_inputs):
        """Returns the mean of the prediction."""
        self.eval()
        self.likelihood.eval()
        with torch.no_grad(), gpytorch.settings.fast_pred_var():
            observed_pred = self.likelihood(self(test_inputs))
            return torch.flatten(observed_pred.mean)

        
def calc_model_trace(model, n_new_samples, n_total_samples, inputs, targets):
    model_trace = []
    for n in range(n_new_samples, n_total_samples, n_new_samples):        
        model.fit(inputs[:n], targets[:n])
        model_trace.append(copy.deepcopy(model))
    return model_trace

# data
x_train = torch.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y_train = torch.sin(x_train * (2 * math.pi)) + torch.randn(x_train.size()) * math.sqrt(0.04)
x_test = torch.linspace(0, 2, 201)

likelihood = gpytorch.likelihoods.GaussianLikelihood()
gpr_model = GaussianProcessRegression(likelihood)

model_trace = calc_model_trace(gpr_model, 5, 5000, x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Python can't free objects that are still being referenced. It sounds like your models are holding on to objects they don't need to. If you posts details about what you're doing, we may be able to help you fix that leak.

Comment: Also, do note that the line `del model` is pretty much useless. `del` is only touching the reference held by the variable `model`, which is going to be freed on the next iteration of the loop anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I added a light version of what I am doing, which is producing the error.

Comment: @Brian61354270 So I guess then the gpytorch.models.ExactGP class causes the open files? Any idea how I can solve this? Or how I could find the part of it that causes it?