# How to release Python memory back to the OS

Tags: python, memory

I have a long running Python script that takes 1-2 hours to complete. It's running on a 4gb container with 1 CPU.

The script fetches and processes data in a for loop. Something like the following:

```
for i in ENOUGH_API_CALLS_TO_TAKE_2_HOURS:
    data = fetch_data()
    process_data(data)
```

The 4gb container crashes halfway through script execution due to lack of memory. There's no way any individual API call comes close to retrieving 4gb of data though.

After using `tracemalloc` to debug, I think Python is slowly eating memory on each API call without releasing it back to the OS. Eventually crashing the process by exceeding memory limits.

I've read [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15492488) that discuss using multiprocessing to ensure memory gets released when tasks complete. But here I only have 1 CPU so I don't have a second processor to work with.

Is there any other way to release memory back to the OS from inside my main thread?

Note I've tried `gc.collect()` without any success.

Comment: `gc.collect()` doesn't release to the OS, it releases for further allocation by the Python interpreter. Most languages don't provide any mechanism to release memory back to the OS at all -- doing it requires defragmenting/compacting your pointer locations and moving the boundary point that represents the last point where your process has any memory space.

Comment: Python is written in C, and C doesn't release memory to the OS either.

Comment: @MarkRansom, ...well, one _could_ write a C program that invokes `brk()`. But yes, in the general case of folks using `malloc()` and `free()` that's of course true.

Comment: In general, processes do not release memory back to the OS; once they allocate memory from the OS, they keep it to reuse later so that they don't have to re-request the same memory over and over. As to why your memory usage keeps growing, we couldn't say without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: "*I only have 1 CPU so I don't have a second processor to work with.*" I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding the literature you've reviewed to date regarding how `multiprocessing` works, and would encourage you to research this more and try it out for yourself. Put another way, there are proportionally **very** few instances where a second physically discrete CPU would ever be present in a given physical hardware configuration.

Comment: (esqew is right -- you can get the memory-management behavior you want from multiprocessing without having more CPUs)

Comment: Cheers I'm realizing I was misinformed, I will start with this.

Comment: I think it may be helpful to know what `process_data` does.

Comment: "I've read threads that discuss using multiprocessing to ensure memory gets released when tasks complete. But here I only have 1 CPU so I don't have a second processor to work with." the number of CPUs is irrelevant. Your computer is probably running hundreds of processes, you can see for yourself by doing something like `ps aux | wc -l`

Comment: Anyway, aside from that solution of using a subprocess, we can only speculate (hardly even that) as to why you seem to be leaking memory. Without a more concrete example, there isn't much else to say

Comment: So you see a growth with `tracemalloc`? That sounds like all that data is still in use and Python can't release it because **you** didn't release it.

Comment: Yep, issue was a memory leak from [Prefect](https://pypi.org/project/prefect/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing does not require you to have multiple physical or logical CPUs. If you look at the task manager on your PC, there are almost certainly more processes running than you have cores or threads.

In this case, your single processor can only be actively working on one task at a time, but it can switch back and forth with a little overhead. This will perhaps extend the overall runtime a bit, but it does solve the problem about eating up resources.

Have you verified that you are actually running out of memory (e.g. by checking logs on your container, or watching the memory usage of your python process in real time)? If you're not sure, it might be valuable to spend time confirming that this is the problem before digging into updating the code into something that will likely be slower (due to the overhead of spawning child processes).

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure it's a memory issue. Logs on the container confirm that, and I've manually tested with `tracemalloc`, AND if I increase container size drastically it runs successfully.

Interesting point on multiprocessing, I did not know this, thank you. I'm still curious to see if there are other solutions too that people suggest.

Comment: @Matt, I wouldn't expect more solutions without a [mre] letting us see the problem ourselves (meaning, giving us enough information to figure out _why_ your process_data call is leaky)